# Android-NestDK An error occured : An eror occured while fetching client info

Tags: android, nest-api

I am trying to run the sample code android-NestDK but I have the error:
An error occured : An eror occured while fetching client info

I think that the problem is to insert the NestClientID and the NestClientSecret but I can' find where I can get them

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer I just change in Constants.java

1-set client id ""
2-set client secret ""
3-set REDIRECT URL to "http://localhost/"

4-and change the URL REDIRECT from nest web site Edit Product

Answer (score 0):

### Get Nest product key

1. Sign up a Nest Account
2. Press "Create New Product" button and fill out a form
3. Go into the product you just created. You'll see "Keys" in the right of website, including Product ID,Product Secret,Authorization URL and Access Token URL.

### Modify the sample code

1. Open Constants.java
2. Modify CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET and REDIRECT_URL
3. Run